# problem with task Ensure that Nginx is stopped

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I wrote a role to run the reactos application the problem occurs with a single task to Ensure that Nginx is stopped . I get a strange error

[image]

if I remove this point from the role, the application closes successfully, but I would like it to work with it as well
previous task works good

```
- name: Ensure nginx is not installed
  apt:
    name: nginx
    state: absent
```

but this doesnt work

```
- name: Ensure that Nginx is stopped
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: nginx
    state: stopped
```

how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **service**. It is compatible in most use cases.

**Service** - Controls services on remote hosts. Supported init systems include BSD init, OpenRC, SysV, Solaris SMF, systemd, upstart.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure nginx is installed
      apt:
        name: nginx
        state: latest

    - name: service started
      service:
        name: nginx
        state: started

    - name: service stopped
      service:
        name: nginx
        state: stopped
```

**sysvinit** - Controls services on target hosts that use the SysV init system.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sysvinit_module.html

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure nginx is installed
      apt:
        name: nginx
        state: latest

    - name: sysvinit started
      sysvinit:
        name: nginx
        state: started

    - name: sysvinit stopped
      sysvinit:
        name: nginx
        state: stopped
```

**Systemd Requirements: A system managed by systemd.**
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure nginx is installed
      apt:
        name: nginx
        state: latest
    
    # this one fails
    - name: systemd started - fail
      systemd:
        name: nginx
        state: started

    # this one fails
    - name: systemd stopped - fail
      systemd:
        name: nginx
        state: stopped
```